# Android Development : Connect Android application to Mysql DB - No data returned on real device

Tags: android, mysql

I'm new to android and I've created sample application that retrieve data from MySql DB (through PHP script) ..and its working fine on android simulator but my problem is when i tested the application on my mobile device there is no data retrieved !

I think this is because my DB on localhost so what is the correct way to retrieve data from my database to real device ? Is there specific IP should i use for this purpose ?

knowing that I've used WAMP server to create mysql database.

Any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: One suggestion is to connect your real device to the same network your test system is connected (Eg,. via WiFi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to host your database on a free database hosting site and connect to that.

You can try http://www.000webhost.com/free-mysql-hosting (Havent tried it but have heard it works)

Other free services:

http://www.frihost.com/
http://www.freesql.org/

Comment: I checked there website .. and i found that you should have registered domain or to create free sub domain ... is there any other free database hosting website without the need to create domain??

Comment: Or is it possible to create my database on WAMP or AMPSS servers but on public IP not localhost ?

Comment: have updated the answer to include other free hosting services ... frihost seems popular.